# How to get client key and client secret for dropbox app

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox, manifold

How to get client key and client secret for dropbox app? I have the app_key and app_secret for app. but i need to get the client key and client secret. Using a [help](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java) provided by drop, I am able to generate access token. this client key and client secret are requested by Manifold connector for dropbox.

Comment: Could you link to "Manifold"? From the terminology you use (client key and client secret), it sounds like Manifold uses OAuth 1, but you have an OAuth 2 access token.

Comment: @smarx , i have place for entering app_key, app_secret, client_key, client_secret to enter. would you be able to tell me if this something resembles Oauth1?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like OAuth 1 to me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want develop an application running on Android platform, you can to go  [developper console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) to set up an application, get client key and client secret.